# How can I get jobs that takes longer than 5 min using dbatools Get-DbaAgentJobHistory?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

Tried running bellow command but "Duration" filter fails.

```
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance instance_name | `
| Get-DbaAgentJobHistory -StartDate '2022-08-02' -EndDate '2022-08-03' `
| Where-Object Duration -gt [TimeSpan]'00:05:00'
```

Error message:

Where-Object : The 'Igt' operator failed: Could not compare "00:01:32" to "[TimeSpan]00:05:00". Error: "Cannot convert
value "[TimeSpan]00:05:00" to type "Sqlcollaborative.Dbatools.Utility.DbaTimeSpanPretty". Error: "Failed to parse as
timespan: [TimeSpan]00:05:00 at [TimeSpan]00:05:00"".
At line:3 char:7
| Where-Object Duration -gt [TimeSpan]'00:05:00'
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Data.DataRow:PSObject) [Where-Object], PSInvalidOperationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: Maybe just do `Where-Object Duration -gt '00:05:00'`

Comment: Thanks. Get an error without timespan casting:


Where-Object : The argument to operator 'Igt' is not valid: Object must be of type TimeSpan..
At line:3 char:1
 Where-Object Duration -gt '00:05:00'
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Data.DataRow:PSObject) [Where-Object], PSArgumentExce 
   ption
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

Just got an alternative:

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT 
    j.name AS 'JobName',
    s.step_id AS 'Step',
    s.step_name AS 'StepName',
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) AS 'RunDateTime',
    ((run_duration/10000*3600 + (run_duration/100)%100*60 + run_duration%100 + 31 ) / 60) AS 'RunDurationMinutes'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s ON j.job_id = s.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON s.job_id = h.job_id 
    AND s.step_id = h.step_id 
    AND h.step_id <> 0
WHERE ((run_duration/10000*3600 + (run_duration/100)%100*60 + run_duration%100 + 31 ) / 60) >= 5
    AND msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) BETWEEN '2022-08-03 09:00:00' AND '2022-08-03 10:30:00'  --Uncomment for date range queries
    --AND j.name = 'TestJob' --Uncomment to search for a single job
ORDER BY RunDurationMinutes DESC, RunDateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old at this point but for future reference

The objects that come back include startdate/enddate of the job as special dba  datetimes that powershell can't convert to timespan implicitly. However, you can do conversion of the start/enddate properties to datetime and then do diff operations that will get you a timespan you can use for comparison or simply check the total minutes/ total milliseconds properties.

example:

```
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance instance_name `
| Get-DbaAgentJobHistory -StartDate '2022-08-02' -EndDate '2022-08-03' `
| Where-Object {(([datetime] $_.enddate)-([datetime]$_.startdate)).totalminutes -ge 5}}
```